# Android Twilio Voice Quickstart gives an error tone saying "An Application error occured"

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-php

I am using twilio voice android quick start and had configured php based server that generates tokens for me.

I am passing "To","From" and "ApplicationSid" params to twilio from android side.
Call UI starts and twilio plays an error tone saying,"We are sorry, a application error occurred".

Is there anything wrong from my mobile end?

Comment: That normally means that Twilio can't reach your TwiML application or there is an error in that application. What does your TwiML app do and can you share the code?

Comment: thanks @phi figured it out,

Comment: Our TWiML app was not rechable for twilio, but it is working now, thanks @philnash

Comment: Good to hear it! Hope the rest of the app goes well :)